# Syntax error at or near "on"

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

In PostgreSQL 8.4.13 why do I please get the syntax error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on" 
LINE: ... references balkan_users(id) check (id <> author) on delete ...
```

for the following 2 statements?

```
create table balkan_users (
        id varchar(32) primary key,
        first_name varchar(64) not null,
        last_name varchar(64),
        female boolean,
        avatar varchar(128),
        city varchar(64),
        mobile varchar(64),
        login timestamp default current_timestamp,
        logout timestamp,
        last_ip inet,
        vip timestamp,
        mail varchar(256),
        green integer,
        red integer,
        medals integer not null default 0
);

create table balkan_rep (
        rep_id serial,
        id varchar(32) references balkan_users(id) check (id <> author) on delete cascade,
        author varchar(32) references balkan_users(id) on delete cascade,
        author_ip inet,
        nice boolean,
        about varchar(256),
        stamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
        primary key(id, author);
);
```

I have also prepared [an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11) to demo my problem.

Comment: Have you tried moving the check constraint behind the "on delete cascade"?

Comment: Then I get: Schema Creation Failed: ERROR: syntax error at end of input:

Comment: That's because you have an extra semicolon after primary key. You apply both these steps and it will work. I just tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***ERROR***:  syntax error at or near "on":

Move the `check` after `on delete cascade`

```
id varchar(32) references balkan_users(id) on delete cascade check (id <> author),
```

***ERROR***: syntax error at end of input:

remove the semicolon at the last column `primary key(id, author);`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/20ebe)